# How to be safe with memory?

Tags: c, string, wrapper

I would like to actually use this wrapper, but the problem is i don't know if it's very safe, yet.

I have a few simple questions regarding using `malloc()`, `calloc()`, and `realloc()`. Here's what I have so far:

string.h

```
typedef struct str str; // pointer for encapsulation
```

string.c

```
struct str
{
    char *buf;
    size_t len;
}
```

Say i have a helper function that simply does this:

```
    str *NEW_STRING()
    {
        str *temp = calloc(1, sizeof (struct str));
        temp->len = 0;
        temp->buf = (char *) malloc(1);
        return temp;
    }
```

Is this safe?  If it is, what would happen if i did something like this:

```
str *A_STRING = NEW_STRING();
A_STRING = NEW_STRING();
```

It would call malloc and calloc twice, is that bad?  Would an initializer be better?

```
void str_init(str *A_STRING)
{
    if (A_STRING)
    {
        free(A_STRING);
    }

    if (A_STRING->buf)
    {
        free(A_STRING->buf);
    }

    A_STRING = calloc(1, sizeof (struct str));
    A_STRING->buf = (char *) malloc(1);
    A_STRING->len = 0;
}
```

Finally, is this a good way to free memory?

```
    void free_string(str *A_STRING)
    {
        if (A_STRING->buf)
        {
            free(A_STRING->buf);
        }
        else
        {
            A_STRING->buf = NULL;
        }

        if (A_STRING)
        {
            free(A_STRING);
        }
        else
        {
            A_STRING = NULL;
        }

        A_STRING->len = 0;
    }
```

Any additional information would be great if included.  I don't want to release anything to the public as if it were a good library, because i am primarily doing this for learning purposes.

Comment: You really can't do much without C++.

Comment: In your second code snippet, `temp` is not checked for allocation failure

Comment: You're accessing memory that you had just freed in `str_init()`... that's not a good start.

Comment: don;t do this. You already have C-Stirings. The problems are known people can work with them. Introducing another C-String library is counter productive and you will introduce a whole new set of problems without adding any real value.

Comment: I would suggest a beginner's book on C. Specifically the section on `malloc()` and `free()` / memory management. There's no free lunch, you need to keep track of it.

Comment: so u suggest i stick with c string library?

Comment: @john. I suggest you learn C++ and use std::string. But failing that the C-String library is better than anything you can write.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lots of errors:

> is this safe? if it is, what would happen if i did something like this:

No.

```
str *NEW_STRING()
{
    str *temp = calloc(1, sizeof (struct str));

    // If calloc fails and returns NULL all the code below is invalid and blows the code up.
```

Next:

> it would call malloc and calloc twice, is that bad? would an initializer be better?

You leak memory.
The second call basically generates a new object the old object is lost and leaks.

Problems in str_init

```
void str_init(str *A_STRING)
{
```

Is this the first time that his method is called?
If so then A_STRING contains a random value (that you are about to FREE).
This will blow the code up.

```
    if (A_STRING)
    {
        free(A_STRING);
    }
```

A_STRING is freed (you can now no longer accesses it).
Any code that does so is bad.

```
    if (A_STRING->buf)   // Bang blow up code.
    {
        free(A_STRING->buf);
    }

    A_STRING = calloc(1, sizeof (struct str));
```

No checking the result of calloc.

```
    A_STRING->buf = (char *) malloc(1);
    A_STRING->len = 0;
}
```

> is this a good way to free memory?

```
void free_string(str *A_STRING)
{
    if (A_STRING->buf)
    {
        free(A_STRING->buf);
    }
    else
    {
        A_STRING->buf = NULL;  // Its already NULL pointless work
    }

    if (A_STRING)
    {
        free(A_STRING);
    }
    else
    {
        A_STRING = NULL;  // ITs already NULL pointless work
    }

    // BANG you just blew up the space shuttle.
    A_STRING->len = 0;
}
```

Comment: In the `free_string()` function, you should check `if (A_STRING)` before you do anything else.  By the time you (the OP) check it, if it was null, the program blew up on `if (A_STRING->buf)`.